# Can't map array with useEffect and React Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, use-effect

I am trying to map over an employee list after useEffect fetches the array and I dispatch it to my redux-state. If I console log it I see an array full of objects, but my component doesn't appear to be re-rendering. Any suggestions?

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { setEmployees } from '../redux/reducers/employeeListReducer'
import employeesService  from '../back-end/services/employees'

const EmployeeList = ({  }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const employees = useSelector(state => state.employeeList) 
  const user = useSelector(state => state.user)

  employeesService.setToken(user.token)

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
    const employeeList = await employeesService.getAll()
         dispatch(setEmployees(employeeList))
     })();
  
  }, [dispatch])
  
  if (employees === null) {
    return <p>Loading Employees...</p>
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {console.log(employees)}
       {employees.map(e =>
        <div key={e.id}>
          {e.name} {e.phone} {e.email}
        </div>  
      )} 
    </div>
  )
}

export default EmployeeList
```

[image: console.log]
[image: reduxstate]

Comment: I fixed it, the root problem was in the reducer.

I changed return [action.data] to return action.data and now it works properly. I read an article about mutating state within the the reducer preventing components from re-rendering.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from the description what may be causing the first issue you describe (there is no `console.log` we can look at to determine why there is a discrepancy), but you cannot call hooks from within callbacks provided to other hooks. This is a limitation of the how hooks are implemented. They depend on always being called in the same order (so you cannot conditionally call a hook function), and they must all have been called by the time your function returns. Details can be found here:

https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html

Basically, you must call hook functions within the top level of a functional component, or within the top level of another hook (for instance, you will see hooks that are implemented using other hooks). All hook functions must have been called by the time your function returns. If the hook is called within a callback, it very likely will be called *after* your function returns. So React warns you about this.

All of that said, moving your declaration of `dispatch` to the top level of your component should resolve this issue:

```js
import React, {useEffect } from 'react'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { setEmployees} from '../redux/reducers/employeeListReducer'
import employeesService  from '../back-end/services/employees'


const EmployeeList = ({ employee }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const employees = useSelector(state => state.employeeList) 
  const user = useSelector(state => state.user)
  employeesService.setToken(user.token)

  useEffect(() => {
    employeesService
      .getAll()
      .then(employeeList => {
         dispatch(setEmployees(employeeList))
      })
  }, [dispatch])

  return (
    <div>
      Employee List Placeholder
       {employees.map(e =>
        <div key={e.id}>
          {e.name} {e.phone} {e.email}
        </div>  
      )} 
    </div>
  )
}

export default EmployeeList
```

Comment: I have edited my post, the console.log shows the employees array with a collection of objects inside it. But my component doesn't seem to re-render as the array is not mapped over to display all of the employees.

So for the second issue if I move dispatch to the top level function I get this error

'React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'dispatch'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps'

Comment: Ah, my bad, the useEffect hook needs dispatch passed in as a dependency. I updated my answer. See if that resolves both issues. Where you have your console.log implies that your elements should match it.

Comment: Thanks, the missing dependency error is fixed, see my latest edits to the code. it seems I still cant map over my employees array. I thought perhaps if I used an async function within useEffect it might help but I have the same problem. Redux state does update correctly as you can see in the image. The employees array is updated with several employee objects, see console.log image, but still my component does not map over it. If I hard code an array of objects it maps fine, I'm rather perplexed, as I understand it a state change should trigger a component re-render. Any other ideas?

Comment: I added an if statement so that it gives a loading message if the employees === null. I can see the loading message but once the data is fetched with employeeService.getAll() and the employee state is updated with the new array the loading message goes away but still the array is not mapped over. This is even more puzzling to me.